# F# Multiline Static Methods

Tags: f#, static-methods

I'm sure this should be obvious, but how do i have a multiline static method in a class? i just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write them in multiple lines. The compiler can infer the method-body per indentation.

```
type Example = class
  static member Foo a b = 
     // ...
     a + b
end
Example.Foo 1 2
```